# Some builds are failing due to java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect exception in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

Some times I am getting below exception for Jenkin build. Please help me how to resolve this issue.

> java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect at
>   java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method) at
>   java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source) at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source) at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source) at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) at
>   java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) at
>   java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) at
>   java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source) at
>   java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source) at
>   sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source) at
>   sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source) at
>   sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source) at
>   sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.(Unknown Source) at
>   sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source) at
>   sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source) at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown
>   Source) at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(Unknown
>   Source) at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown
>   Source) at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(Unknown
>   Source) at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown
>   Source) at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown
>   Source) at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
>   at
>   hudson.plugins.fitnesse.FitnesseExecutor.getHttpBytes(FitnesseExecutor.java:247)
>   at
>   hudson.plugins.fitnesse.FitnesseExecutor$1.run(FitnesseExecutor.java:231)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Xml results saved as
>   windows-1252 to
>   D:\Automation\JenkinWorkspace\test-reports\fitnesse-results.xml

Answer (score 0):

See if this is related to [issue JENKINS-13696](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-13696):

> If I understand this issue correctly, I am having the same problem.
>   It appears that the plugin is trying to connect to FitNesse on the master (the FitNesse server is started correctly on the slave).
>   As a work around, I need to start the FitNesse server manually on the slave machine, and specify the option "Fitnesse instance is already running".
>
> My error is

```
Connnecting to http://localhost:8085/RiskManagement.SomeSuitePage.AnotherSuitePage?suite&format=xml&includehtml
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

The [OP ramesh sriram](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4362499/ramesh-sriram) mentions [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47918540/some-builds-are-failing-due-to-java-net-connectexception-connection-refused-co/47918592?noredirect=1#comment82805099_47918592) the cause of the error:

The port is closed/down.

Comment: I found that Fitnesse port is down in the server. Hence I got this exception.

Comment: @rameshsriram OK. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.